# Size of a java ServerSocket queue

Tags: java, sockets

Can we get the state (free space) of a java `ServerSocket` **queue** ??

The goal is to throw an exception when it's full ...

---

Some details about the [`ServerSocket`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) queue :

> Class ServerSocket

...

> ServerSocket()

...

> The maximum queue length for incoming
>   connection indications (a request to
>   connect) is set to 50. If a connection
>   indication arrives when the queue is
>   full, the connection is refused.

...

> ServerSocket(int port, int backlog)

...

> The maximum queue length for incoming
>   connection indications (a request to
>   connect) is set to the backlog
>   parameter. If a connection indication
>   arrives when the queue is full, the
>   connection is refused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the queue is managed by the OS, out of the SDK's purview.

Comment: but the javadoc says that you can specify the length of the queue : "The maximum queue length ... is set to the backlog parameter." it means that the SDK has an access to it ? no ?

Comment: You can see the source code for yourself, but yes, the SDK passes along the requested queue size to the OS, which establishes the server socket and its queue.